# Как в Git вернуться к нужному коммиту и продолжить работу с него?

Tags: git, git-reset

Я закоммитил последние изменения в работе и сделал пуш на гитхаб, но потом у меня редактор кода начал выдавать ошибку о незакрытой скобке } и как мне показалось это просто глюк и я прописал git reset --hard HEAD~1 и откатился. Мне интересно а каким образом я могу выбирать коммиты из истории сохранений и начинать работу с какого-то из них? Подскажите команду

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> git reset --hard HEAD~1
> ```

Вот вместо `HEAD~1` поставить хэш нужного коммита из истории.

Ну и само собой, можно делать не только `reset`, но и `checkout` по хешу. И вообще, во все команды, умеющие работать с ветками, можно вместо имени ветки подставить хэш.

Comment: я знаю хэш и прописываю git checkout ad4536f88d1c720b446a6db478816221ea337182 и он мне выдает ошибку error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        src/css/style.css
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting

Comment: Ну так у тебя незакоммиченные изменения, которые он по умолчанию не затирает. Добавь флаг `--force`, тогда затрёт вроде. Ну или просто дискардни всё предвалительно.

Comment: а можешь показать,как это надо прописать?

Comment: Вроде бы должно работать `git checkout --force ad4536f88d1c720b446a6db478816221ea337182`.